# Dual British/German citizenship after Brexit

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, dual-citizenship, brexit

My understanding is that generally, German citizenship is lost upon intentionally receiving another citizenship. There is an exception for this rule for other EU countries, and there is a possibility to receive permission to apply for another citizenship while keeping the German one.

How are these applications handled? Are these for extraordinary cases only, or is it plausible to receive this permission as an ordinary German resident of the UK?

Comment: According to https://uk.diplo.de/uk-en/02/citizenship/retention-of-citizenship/2451414 the administrative procedure for naturalisation in other (non-EU) countries whilst retaining German nationality takes into account the applicant’s private motives. The applicant will need to provide evidence of continuing ties with Germany and that there are substantial reasons for acquiring the other nationality. So it seems plausible, but probably difficult.

Comment: @Traveller Thanks for the link, that is clearer than the info I'd been aware of previously. I still don't feel I understand their criteria well though.

Comment: Traveller, I think that comment should be an answer. Arno: I think a decision would be very dependent on the exact facts - how strong exactly are your ties to Germany, and how substantial exactly are your reasons for acquiring say UK citizenship. I assume it can be decided before you start the process of getting UK citizenship.